# Added SSD to mid 2011 27" iMac. How do I keep user accounts on HDD and only use SSD for OS and Apps

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd, migration

I've added a 240GB SSD to my mid 2011 27" iMac.

I installed macOS Sierra to SSD and then migrated apps and settings to SSD but left users data on HDD.

After booting into the SSD, I opened:

system prefs > user accounts > advanced options

Then I pointed the SSD user account to my home directory on the HDD and restarted.

Now when I log into my user account (SSD) none of my files or preferences are working or updating and I keep getting an error about keychain missing.

Did I miss a crucial step? How do I fix this?

BTW, I can't migrate my users over to the SSD as there isn't nearly enough space.

Also, I have been using iCloud drive for my documents and desktop in macOS sierra, perhaps that's part of the problem?

Comment: Would keeping your user accounts on the SSD be an option if you can keep your iTunes Library, Photos Library, etc still stored on the HDD? Typically these two libraries are the big data hogs for most users.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just a permissions problem. Since macOS Sierra doesn't give you the ability to fix permissions, I'll just post this here in case anyone else needs it:

To reset permissions from the terminal:

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / $(id -u)
```